# NuGet.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported warning

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget, package

I am getting this warning in Visual Studio 2013 for some of my projects:

```
NuGet.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported
```

My Main WCF project in the solution file has this:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-01C04F79EFBC}") = "WCF.Project", "Website\WCF.Project.csproj", "{AEFE3DD8-6E77-4449-9632-E2F0BADB6EBC}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = ".nuget", ".nuget", "{778ACFB4-FB04-4E26-93DD-260E7B406E48}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .nuget\NuGet.Config = .nuget\NuGet.Config
        .nuget\NuGet.exe = .nuget\NuGet.exe
        .nuget\NuGet.targets = .nuget\NuGet.targets
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

In my WCF project file it has:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
```

Now that I look at it.. it looks like there is double in the for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, look like this was just some weird merge issue in TFS, was duplicating the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Despite this is an old question I got to it having exactly same error after migrating VS2015 solution to VS2017.
Cleaning the NuGet cache solved this issue (see the picture).

[image: VS2017 (partial) settings dialog.]

HTH!

**Edit**: Problem re-appeared when building multiple projects. So, maybe a better approach is to move all sources to a new project with (possibly!) the same name, or at least same namespace/assembly name. Comparing converted/generated VS2015 and VS2017 .csproj files revealed a much more concise project structure in VS2017 even after downloading missing NuGets, not sure if it is worth editing each and every .csproj instead of replacing it with a newly generated one.

Answer (score 0):

For others that maybe have this problem (like me) perhaps this will help:

(uninstall other VS or clean props folders)

[VS Community - Nuget: targets and props warning about cannot be imported again](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110056/nuget-targets-and-props-warning-about-cannot-be-im.html)